# LINQ - order by distance (calculated value)

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, xna

What I would like is to loop through each item of a List in ascending order of distance (so the nearest targets are used first).

```
foreach (ShipCompartment enemyComp in enemy.ListOfCompartments.OrderBy(...))
```

The problem is that the distance is not a member of the class. Therefore I can't use:

```
foreach (ShipCompartment enemyComp in enemy.ListOfCompartments
    .OrderBy(c => c.Distance))
```

The code used to calculate distance is:

```
// Get distance between player and enemy compartments
float distanceToTarget = Vector2.Distance(playerComp.Position,
    enemyComp.Position);
```

How can I incorporate the calculation into OrderBy()? I've looked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920238/xna-find-nearest-vector-from-player) but it only returns the nearest Vector2.

Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried something like `foreach (ShipCompartment enemyComp in enemy.ListOfCompartments.OrderBy(c => Vector2.Distance(playerComp.Position, c.Position)))`?

Comment: @Rowland Perfect! So simple, yet I never thought of it! Please write it up as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple option would be to move the function call to the `OrderBy` call, so something like:

```
foreach (ShipCompartment enemyComp in enemy.ListOfCompartments.OrderBy(c => Vector2.Distance(playerComp.Position, c.Position)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution if you need Distance generally (and not only for sorting) is to use Select to create a new structure that contains a definition of Distance and then use OrderBy. For example:

For the data structure:

```
class Coordinates
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
foreach(var coordinate in coordinates.Select(x=> new 
    {
        Value = x.Value,
        Longitude = x.Longitude,
        Latitude = x.Latitude,
        Distance = x.Longitude + x.Latitude
    }).OrderBy(x=>x.Distance))
    Process(coordinate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own custom comparer and pass it as OrderBy parameter:

```
public class ShipCompartmentDistanceComparer : IComparer<ShipCompartment>
        {
            public int Compare(ShipCompartmentDistance x,  y)
            {
                float distanceToTargetX = Vector2.Distance(playerComp.Position, x.Position);
                float distanceToTargetY = Vector2.Distance(playerComp.Position, y.Position);
                if (distanceToTargetX > distanceToTargetY)
                    return 1;
                if (distanceToTargetX < distanceToTargetY)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
```

Then you just need to call:

```
foreach (ShipCompartment enemyComp in enemy.ListOfCompartments
    .OrderBy(c => c, new ShipCompartmentDistanceComparer()))
```